# no viable alternative at input antlr

Tags: parsing, python-3.x, input, antlr, lexer

I have to do a lexer and a parser for Python using ANTLR, but when I run with this input: 
print 99 appears this error: "no viable alternative at input print99". 
Why puts all together?? 
I really need your help for this. 
I try everything and I dont know whats is wrong.

```
***This is my Lexer:***

lexer grammar LexerPython;

options {
    language=Python3;
}

fragment L : [a-z];
fragment D : [0-9];
NUM  : '0' | ([1-9] D*);
ID   :  L (L|D)*;

//PALABRAS RESERVADAS
DEF : 'def';

IF : 'if' ;

ELSE : 'else' ;

//INTEGER

//STRING

LEN : 'len' ;

RETURN : 'return' ;

PRINT : 'print' ;

WHILE : 'while' ;

INDENT : '\t' ;

DEDENT : 'dedent' ;

NEWLINE : '\r\n' ;

//SIMBOLOS NUMERICOS

SUMA : '+' ;

RESTA : '-' ;

MULTIPLICACION : '*' ;

DIVISION : '/' ;

MAYOR : '>' ;

MENOR : '<' ;

MAYOR_IGUAL : '>=' ;

MENOR_IGUAL : '<=' ;

IGUAL : '=' ;

IGUAL_IGUAL : '==' ;

//OTROS SIMBOLOS

COMA : ',' ;

DOS_PUNTOS : ':' ;

PARENTESIS_ABIERTO : '(' ;

PARENTESIS_CERRADO : ')' ;

CORCHETE_ABIERTO : '[' ;

CORCHETE_CERRADO : ']' ;

WS : ' '+ -> skip ;


***And this is my PARSER:***

program : statement (statement)* ;

statement : defstatement | ifstatement | returnstatement | printstatement | whilestatement | assignstatement | functioncallstatement ;

defstatement : DEF ID PARENTESIS_ABIERTO arglist PARENTESIS_CERRADO DOS_PUNTOS sequence ;

arglist : ID  (COMA ID)* ;

moreargs : ID ;

ifstatement : IF expression DOS_PUNTOS sequence ELSE DOS_PUNTOS sequence ;

whilestatement : WHILE expression DOS_PUNTOS sequence ;

returnstatement : RETURN expression NEWLINE ;

printstatement : PRINT expression NEWLINE ;

assignstatement : ID IGUAL expression NEWLINE ;

functioncallstatement : primitiveexpression PARENTESIS_ABIERTO expressionlist PARENTESIS_CERRADO NEWLINE ;

sequence : NEWLINE INDENT morestatements DEDENT ;

morestatements : statement  (statement)* ; 

expression : additionexpression comparison ;

comparison : (MENOR|MAYOR|MENOR_IGUAL|MAYOR_IGUAL|IGUAL_IGUAL) 

additionexpression (comparison)* ;

additionexpression : multiplicationexpression additionfactor ;

additionfactor : (SUMA|RESTA) multiplicationexpression (additionfactor)* ;

multiplicationexpression : elementexpression multiplicationfactor ;

multiplicationfactor : (MULTIPLICACION|DIVISION) elementexpression (multiplicationfactor)* ;

elementexpression : primitiveexpression elementaccess ;

elementaccess : CORCHETE_ABIERTO expression CORCHETE_CERRADO  (elementaccess)* ;

//functioncallexpression : primitiveexpression ( expressionlist ) ;

expressionlist : expression (COMA expression)* ;

moreexpressions : expression ;

primitiveexpression : NUM | ID | PARENTESIS_ABIERTO expression PARENTESIS_CERRADO | listexpression | LEN PARENTESIS_ABIERTO expression PARENTESIS_CERRADO | /*functioncallexpression*/ ;

listexpression : CORCHETE_ABIERTO expressionlist CORCHETE_CERRADO ;
```

Comment: Your parser doesn't handle spaces between commands that I can see. You're just skipping all spaces, but spaces are important between commands.

Comment: And how I do that?? Like this, for example:                                                   printstatment : PRINT ' ' expresision ;        Like that??

Comment: It might be like: `ifstatement : IF WS expression DOS_PUNTOS sequence WS ELSE DOS_PUNTOS sequence ;`. You already defined `WS`, so don't skip it, just adjust your syntax to account for it. You maybe also need one for *optional* whitespace.

Comment: Doesn't work like you say. Throws me this error: no viable alternative at input 'print ' . Me input was print "hello"

Comment: If you wrote this code yourself, you should have no problem adjusting it to account for spaces. Work it out yourself. I'm not going to solve it for you; I'm giving *suggestions*. On another note, since this is for **Python 3**, parentheses are required. E.g: `print("hello")`

Comment: Have you considered using an existing grammar? https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python3/Python3.g4

Comment: Also, you have made a common error: as "print" matches both the token PRINT and the token ID, and ID is defined first, "print" (and all other keywords) will always match ID and never PRINT.

Comment: I can fixe it. In my lexer i have this, for example: ELSE : 'else' ; I have to convert that to this: ELSE : 'Else' with the firts 'E' of the token in upper case letter. I do this in all my tokens (def,if,else,return,print) and its works. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Adrian Leonhard, I can't use an existing grammar because is a proyect, an I have to use the grammar that my teacher give me so he can check if ir right or not

Comment: Should it be: `printstatement : PRINT PARENTESIS_ABIERTO expression PARENTESIS_CERRADO NEWLINE ;`?

Comment: Yes, thats it how should be, but the grammar from the teacher doesn't work like that, its a miniPython grammar so have a lot of thinks that are different from the original Python. Thanks